# Serverless: how to remove one function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless

I am using serverless to deploy my API on AWS.

In serverless, it allows to deploy a single function:

```
sls deploy -f <function name>
```

But it doesn't allow to remove a single function:

```
sls remove // will remove all functions.
```

Is there any way to remove single function which won't impact to other functions?

Comment: Can't you just remove it from your serverless file and then do a deploy?

Comment: yes, it worked, why didn't I think about that way?

Comment: I will close this question. Thanks @justin.m.chase, good to ask and you replied so fast.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

@justin.m.chase suggested:

Simply remove the function in serverless.yml, then run full deploy

```
sls deploy
```

the function is removed (Lambda + API Gateway). Perfecto!

Comment: -1 this is wrong, if you remove function from serverless.yml and then try to deploy, it gives error "UPDATE ROLLBACK FAILED".

Comment: @Donato try deleting the .serverless folder (its invisible on mac so you must make it visible with command + shift + dot)

Comment: Will say that I just did this. 
1) Removed function from serverless.yml
2) Deleted .serverless
3) `sls deploy`
It took a very very long time to redeploy and I thought something was wrong, but it eventually worked and the lambda function is gone. Word of caution again: do not manually delete in the AWS GUI, will cause many problems.

Answer (score -1):

As Peter Pham said, remove the function from serverless.yml and do a full:

```
sls deploy
```

If you try to delete the function manually in AWS it causes a lot of headaches.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's a bit old but the deploy pain of serverless is still a thing.

I recently developed a cli which enables to build microservices in AWS, taking advantage of AWS sam cli (hence the cli name: **Rocketsam**).

The cli enables caching per function (no more full deploy to the microservice if only one function code changed).
It also has additional features such as splitting the template file to per function, sharing code across functions, fetching logs and more :)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rocketsam

Currently the cli supports building functions in python 3.6 only, but can be easily extended in the future depending on demand.

Answer (score -14):

I know this question is over a year old and has been closed but the correct way to remove a single function is to specify it by name which you almost had:

`sls remove -f <function name>`

Comment: This is incorrect. The -f argument is not respected and the entire stack is removed.

Comment: this answer should be removed from here

Comment: I was looking for something to remove entire stack. `-f` wasen't needed though. Thanks for the answer. Upvoted!

Comment: @AnumSheraz while it might have helped you, your needs were very different from the actual question. I have no idea why you would think upvoting a dangerous answer would be a good idea...